# Visual Studio (2013/2015/2017) WebAPI issue (add mvc controller menu disappeared after add APIController to project)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Since I've added WebAPI to my existing ASP.NET MVC 4 project, when I want to add a new MVC controller, I am unable to do so because Visual Studio will only show the WebAPI controller creation dialog.

Is there any solution to this problem? (I have tested it in both 2013 and 2015)

**Updated**

I have also test it in VS 2017, it has this issue likewise !
[image: Screen Shot from VS add controller Menu]

Comment: The controller is just a class. You can add a new class and make it inherited from "controller" which is MVC controller and not ApiController.

Comment: @MarcusH an MVC controller

Comment: I know it, but just want to know is there anyway to fix this issue?